# stack around the variable 'var' was corrupted

Tags: c, pointers

The problem seems to be the "*p = 20;" command, although I simply do not get why. Whenever I add it, I get the error "stack around the variable 'var' was corrupted".

```
main(void)
{
    int* p;
    int var;
    p = &var;
    *p = 16;    
    p++;        
    *p = 20;    
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Where `p` is pointing after the increment?

Comment: But that's exactly what `p++;  *p = 20;` does. It corrupts stack around `var`.

Comment: Doesn't it point to the (previous address + 4 bytes) address? For example, if p pointed to address 200 at 1st, won't it point to the address 204 now?

Comment: And what is located at that address?

Comment: @Leet: Yes, it does. And that is exactly how you corrupt the stack: by writing at the address that does not belong to you.

Comment: @AnT: Could there be a chance that I'd be able to use that address? I mean, me not having access at it, means that it's already taken by another part of the code, or I'd be unable to access it no matter what? I thought that using "int* p = malloc(2*sizeof(int));" would be redundant here.

Comment: You can't use memory that was not allocated. Period. Not in pure C.

Comment: @Leet: Yes, there's is a random chance. Obviously, you should not even try to rely on it. And in debug configurations compilers often intentionally leave a strip of memory - "no man's land" - between variables. They do it specifically to catch what you just did. You wrote that `20` into a "no man's land" area, which was immediately noticed by the debug code.

Comment: @AnT I would refrain from giving the OP the impression he can do this.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Well, it's settled then. Thanks.

Comment: @AnT: You mentioned that they do it specifically to catch what I did. Wouldn't I get the same error, were that part of the code not a "no man's land" part? Being occupied by some other part of the code, that is.

Comment: @Leet: When several variables are stored next to each other (without a "no man's land" area in between), then by doing this you would normally clobber another variable (stored in memory after your `var`). Normally it woudn't be caught immediately. Most of the time it would destroy your program's invariants and make it behave unpredictably.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I am trying to get the underlying logic behind everything pointer-related. So what I am searching for isn't simply "You can do this, but  you cannot do that" advice.

Comment: @AnT: Thank you for your clarification! Have a good day/night!

Comment: "Doesn't it point to the (previous address + 4 bytes) address" No. It point one past the previous `int` element. There is no guarantee an `int` has 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

After this statement

```
p++;
```

the pointer `p` does not point to a valid object (it points now to the memory beyond the object `var` of the type `int`). Thus this statement

```
*p = 20;
```

results in undefined behavior. That is

> stack around the variable 'var' was corrupted

Comment: Supposing that p pointed to the address 200 in the beginning. Why won't (p++) point to the address 204 now? If it does, why would it be considered invalid? Thank you for your answer by the way.

Comment: It's certainly possible that in your example `p` could be at address 204. But there's nothing that says you're allowed to access that memory or what can happen if you try. It's undefined behavior.

Comment: @Leet Yes, it will have the address 204. However the memory at this address is not occupied by a valid object of type int. It can be occupied for example by some code of the function. In this case it will be overwritten and the integrity of the function will be broken.

Comment: @Vlad from Moskow: Thank you! So there'd be a chance I'd be able to access it, were it not occupied by another part of the program, but it would just be luck, right? Are there any other reasons I might not get access to it?

Comment: @Leet It is undefined behavior. It is enough reason for not to do that.

Comment: @Leet change `var` to an int array and there will be no problem

Answer (score 0):

Vlad from Moscow's answer is correct. Here's some additional information on why that is that I thought would be useful.

The reason you are getting this error is because you're overwriting protected memory on the stack, which Vlad from Moscow has shown to you. compilers will protect you against stack corruption. There are various ways to implement this, but one way is to use a "canary," which is just a value or values at a specific memory location. If those values are changed, the compiler knows that the stack was corrupted, and can give you an error message like "stack around the variable 'var' was corrupted." In your case, the memory location 4 bytes beyond the variable var is probably a canary value on the stack (if your particular comipler uses canaries), which you changing, and that causes the error.

See the Wikipedia article on [buffer overflow protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection) for more information.

Here's an excerpt from the article:

> Typically, buffer overflow protection modifies the organization of stack-allocated data so it includes a canary value that, when destroyed by a stack buffer overflow, shows that a buffer preceding it in memory has been overflowed. By verifying the canary value, execution of the affected program can be terminated, preventing it from misbehaving or from allowing an attacker to take control over it. Other buffer overflow protection techniques include bounds checking, which checks accesses to each allocated block of memory so they cannot go beyond the actually allocated space, and tagging, which ensures that memory allocated for storing data cannot contain executable code.

Edit:

I actually really like the next paragraph in the wiki article as well:

> Overfilling a buffer allocated on the stack is more likely to influence program execution than overfilling a buffer on the heap because the stack contains the return addresses for all active function calls. However, similar implementation-specific protections also exist against heap-based overflows.